# regular expression to treat unbalanced braces as a word

Tags: tcl

I am getting an error message in this regex when line contains unbalanced braces.

```
set line "a b { c{}"
set lst [regexp -all -inline {^(\s*(\S*)\s*)*(\{(.*)\})?(\s*(\S*)\s*)*$} $line]
set lst [lindex $lst 0]
set firstelement [lindex $lst 0]
```

How to avoid such cases and treat unbalanced braces as a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a string from an arbitrary source (like a user) there's no guarantee at all that it is a well-formed list. Now `regexp -inline` returns a list of what it matched, but the elements of that list are strings (unless you use the `-indices` option, of course) and that means that you can't safely use `lindex` on them to pick out the pieces.

The safe way to get the first “word”, assuming you define “word” to be “sequence of non-whitespace characters” (the usual user definition), is to do this:

```
set firstWord [lindex [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $item] 0]
```

It's a bit ugly, but it's totally safe. (In fact, for the *first* word only, use `regexp -inline {\S+} $item` on its own, but that won't let you get later words.)

Using `split` to break a string into words is also possible, but that strongly assumes that the word separator is a single (whitespace-by-default) character and does something that you might not expect if you have multi-whitespace separators, or leading and trailing whitespace. Frankly, it's more useful for dividing up non-whitespace separated strings (e.g., a file into lines, an `/etc/passwd` record into fields) or for turning a string into the list of its characters (with an empty second argument).

Answer (score 1):

The regexp command returns a list. You then take the first element of the list. But in the final line you then treat that element as a list - but it is not guaranteed to be so - hence the actual string content matters. Instead, if you want to deal with this item as a list you need to use `split` and convert it into words:

```
% split "a b {" " "
a b \{
```

In your case:

```
set lst [lindex $lst 0]
set firstelement [lindex [split $lst " "] 0]
```

You may also want to look into `subst`. It looks like you are trying to read poorly specified tcl lists as input and doing some parsing to get them as a proper tcl list. In which case, `subst -nocommands [lindex $lst 0]` might be more helpful to you. For example:

```
% lindex [subst -nocommands [lindex $lst 0]] 2
c{}
```

Note that this is the content of the braced part of $line.

Comment: How on earth does `subst` help?